# Projection matrix implies existence of an orthogonal matrix with certain property?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need help understanding the following assertion in a textbook.

> Let $Z$ be an $n \times r$ matrix with $r < n$ and rank equal to $r$. Since $H = Z(Z^T Z)^{-1}Z^T$ is a projection matrix of rank $r$, there is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $\Gamma$ such that 
>   $$
> \Gamma = [\Gamma_1 \, \Gamma_2],
> $$
>   $$
> H\Gamma = [\Gamma_1 \, 0],
> $$
>   where $\Gamma_1$ is $n \times r$ and $\Gamma_2$ is $n \times (n-r)$.

Where does $\Gamma$ come from? And how can I determine it from Z?

For concreteness, say 
$$
Z = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
1 & b \\
1 & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

As $H\Gamma = [\Gamma_1 \, 0],\ \ \  \Gamma^{-1}H\Gamma = 
\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
I_r&0\\ 0&0
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ hence $\Gamma$ is the matrix with coordinates of the eigenvectors of $H$. This is (this can be taken) orthogonal because $H$ is symetric.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ contain orthonormal bases of $\mathcal{R}(Z)$ and $\mathcal{R}(Z)^{\perp}$, where $\mathcal{R}(Z)$ is the column-space of $Z$ and $\mathcal{R}(Z)^{\perp}$ its orthogonal complement.

Any $\Gamma_1$ such that $\mathcal{R}(\Gamma_1)=\mathrm{R}(Z)$ can be expressed as $\Gamma_1=ZB$, where $B$ is $r\times r$ nonsingular matrix. So one obtains
$$
H\Gamma_1=Z(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TZB=ZB=\Gamma_1.
$$

The matrix $\Gamma_2$ is a basis of $\mathcal{R}(Z)^{\perp}$. Since its columns span the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{R}(Z)$, we have $Z^T\Gamma_2=0$ and hence
$$
H\Gamma_2=Z(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T\Gamma_2=0.
$$

Note that $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are far from being unique, only their column-spans are fixed, that is, $\mathcal{R}(Z)=\mathcal{R}(\Gamma_1)$ and $\mathcal{R}(Z)^{\perp}=\mathcal{R}(\Gamma_2)$.

A particular *orthonormal* matrix $\Gamma_1$ can be defined by $\Gamma_1=Z(Z^TZ)^{-1/2}$ (that is, $B=(Z^TZ)^{-1/2}$). It is easy to see that $\Gamma_1$ is orthogonal.

Alternatively (and also in practice), you can compute these matrices using QR factorisation algorithms. If you want only $\Gamma_1$, you can compute the ("economy") QR factorisation of $Z$ (e.g., using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm) such that $Z=QR$ and set $\Gamma_1=Q$ (here, $Q$ is $n\times r$ orthogonal matrix). If you want to compute both $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$, you can use the full QR factorisation (based, e.g., on the Householder transformations) which gives you an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix $Q$ and $r\times r$ upper triangular $R$ such that
$$
Z=Q\tilde{R}=[Q_1 Q_2]\begin{bmatrix}R\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
and set $\Gamma_1=Q_1$ and $\Gamma_2=Q_2$.